# What categories of questions do we not have many questions in?

Tags: discussion, questions

I just heard the term "moral causality" and thought, I wonder if someone's asked about that on Christianity Stackexchange, and that brought 0 results.

There are certainly depths of Christianity that we have not plumbed, can anybody think of what they are?  Maybe we could start 2023 out with a new direction on aspects of theology heretofore unpoised?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting or important tags that don't have too many questions include (I'm looking at those with under 20):

- Church branches: [christadelphians](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christadelphians), [modalism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modalism), [oneness-pentecostalism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oneness-pentecostalism) (coincidentally, both have the same number of questions!), [reformed-baptist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reformed-baptist)
- Church history: [counter-reformation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-reformation)
- Church polity: [anglican-ordinariate](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anglican-ordinariate), [church-magisterium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-magisterium)
- Creeds: [athanasian-creed](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/athanasian-creed), [chalcedonian-definition](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chalcedonian-definition), [filioque](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filioque)
- Doctrines: [amillennialism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amillennialism), [divine-simplicity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divine-simplicity), [essence-energies](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/essence-energies), [general-revelation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-revelation), [limited-atonement](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limited-atonement), [marks-of-the-church](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marks-of-the-church), [miaphysitism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miaphysitism), [providence](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/providence), [regeneration](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regeneration), [sola-gratia](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sola-gratia), [theosis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theosis), [union-with-christ](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/union-with-christ)
- People: [bonhoeffer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bonhoeffer), [irenaeus](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irenaeus), [john-piper](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-piper), [karl-barth](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karl-barth), [nt-wright](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nt-wright), [origen](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origen), [tertullian](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tertullian), [zwingli](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zwingli)
- Practices: [bible-reading](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible-reading), [pastoral-care](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pastoral-care)
- Theology & hermeneutics: [biblical-theology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblical-theology), [npp](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/npp)

Bonus: we can never have too many [nephilim](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nephilim) questions!